# Mac 11.4 custom app shortcuts disappearing

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcut

I just updated to macOS 11.4 on a 2020 M1 mac mini.
When creating an app shortcut in system preferences, everything works normally. I select an app, create the shortcut, then everything works.

Upon closing system preferences and reopening, the custom shortcuts list disappears. This makes altering the shortcuts impossible so if there was an error, I have to start ALL OVER. Anyone else experiencing this problem?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: after creating shortcuts for other apps, I noticed this particular error is only happening with Reason 11, a music application. This may be a compatibility issue with the app which leads me down a different path. Maybe it has something to do with preferences...

Comment: after deleting the preferences for the Reason 11 app, the problem persists. This is weird!